# Lodash map with function: how to pass to function another parameter?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using lodash map in this way

```
const newCollection = _.map(
    responseJson.OldCollection, 
    AddDetailsToSingleItems
);
```

having

```
function AddDetailsToSingleItems (item ) {
 ... 
}
```

I ask you, please, what's the right syntax to pass a parameter to this function.

I'd like to have

```
function AddDetailsToSingleItems (item, myNewParam ) {
 ... 
}
```

(note the `myNewParam`).

I don't kow how to tell to loadsh map to pass every single item to my function *and* to pass one more param when calling `AddDetailsToSingleItems`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't explained where `myNewParam` is coming from, but I assume you have that data somewhere.

Lodash [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#map) (just like normal JavaScript [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) accepts a function as its second argument to be run on all elements of the supplied list. You can just pass an anonymous function:

```
_.map(
  responseJson.OldCollection, 
  item => AddDetailsToSingleItems(item, myNewParam)
);
```

Comment: YES ! this was exactly what I need... I tried binding but without success... Thanks a lot. Thans also for editing my OP, I was editing too but you were faster!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function that knows the value of `myNewParam`, but only accepts the `item` parameter like this:

```
var myNewParam = 'param_value';

var AddDetailsFn = function(m) {
  return function(item) {
    return AddDetailsToSingleItems(item, m);
  };
};

const newCollection = _.map(
    responseJson.OldCollection, 
    AddDetailsFn(myNewParam)
);
```

This way, `_.map` only sees a function that takes a single parameter.  The `AddDetailsFn` returns a function that takes a single parameter, but already has the value of `myNewParam` captured.  You can also be more succinct with:

```
const newCollection = _.map(
    responseJson.OldCollection,
    function(item) { return AddDetailsToSingleItems(item, myNewParam); }
);
```